# Angular 10 <input type=number> thousand separator

Tags: angular, angular-material, input-mask

In my Angular 10 project, I have some `mat-form-fields` with `<input type=number>` that I want to add a thousand separator to.

Meaning, as the user is entering a number, the program should insert commas every three digits and not in the floating part either.

So for example, if the user is typing **1200.5869** the user should see this number in their input field as they're typing: **1,200.5869**. (which is very common in cryptocurrency trading websites by the way.)

Things I have tried so far:

- ngx-mask library which works fine when I change the input type to tel but not when it's number.
- writing my own angular directive that changes the input as the user is typing which I couldn't do really. because commas are not allowed in input type = number and it would just delete the input value whenever the directive tried to insert a comma.

This is my input `.html` code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>amount</mat-label>
    <input
      type="number"
      matInput
      [min]="0.1"
      [step]="0.1"
      formControlName="quantity"
    />
    <span matSuffix>
      USDT
    </span>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have the decimal pipe (angular built-in pipe).

It should be look something like this:

`{{ value_expression | number [ : digitsInfo [ : locale ] ] }}`

You can have a closer look at angular API:https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Comment: This is true but it does not answer the question. The question is "How can I format the values behind the input tag?" How can the decimal pipe be applied to the input tag?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented similar functionality.

I've used ControlValueAccesor to create a custom input.

It uses text input but returns a number value.

https://npmjs.com/package/ng-number-input